# Specifying label values in en.yml in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, localization

I am writing a webpage where I need to have some radio button for choices.

The code is as follows:

```
  - Person.food_type.options[:flags].each do |cs|
    = radio_button_tag "Person[food_type]", cs, @Person.food_type == cs ? true : false
    = label_tag(:food_type,cs.to_s.capitalize, :class => "checkbox_label")
```

For each label that gets generated, I would like to specify a value for that label in 
en.yml file.

How can I define these label values in en.yml ?

for example, instead of the label being:

[radio button] spicyfood,

I'd like it to be:

[radio button] Spicy Food.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do something like this :

```
- Person.food_type.options[:flags].each do |cs|
  = radio_button_tag "Person[food_type]", cs, @Person.food_type == cs ? true : false
  = label_tag(:food_type,t('.label_#{cs}'), :class => "checkbox_label")
```

and add the value in you .yml file.

You can also change, or create, your `to_s` method in your model.

Comment: I tried your modification above, used double quotes instead of single.

But in my en.yml 

If I write 

xyz:
  chinese: "Spicy food"

It won't reflect the changes.Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: In the generated code you should have something like "missing translation : en.my_view.label_abc" you should add, in your .yml, the missing translation. See the documentation here : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html.

Comment: I used:

    = label_tag(:food_type,t(cs), :class => "checkbox_label")

Defined the value in .yml and it worked. Thanks!